# Where should I create the Core Data Stack

Tags: iphone, core-data

I want to add core data to my app. should i need to add the core data methods in app delegate .h and .m files after adding the framework. please help

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create the core data stack later on in a view controller.

The examples and the templates create it for you in the AppDelegate. If you don't know how to do it, just create a dummy project with Core data and copy the boilerplate over.

Comment: And don't forget to import the CoreData header in the appname.pch file :)